Changing permissions on video or audio stops all WebRTC MediaStreams
I'm doing a web application in React that resembles a web conference app, so I require camera and microphone access.
When I request access for the camera and microphone, I do it with a single prompt, as encouraged in the Media Capture and Streams W3C Draft. So I get access to both devices and everything works fine.
The problem I have is the following - I have these three objects:
let both = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});

// Separate streams
let video = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false});
let audio = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});

They all have different MediaStream IDs, and different MediaStreamTrack's IDs. So they can't be related or associated.
But, when I revoke the permissions to the video or audio (I'm using Google Chrome, so this should be up to date), the three MediaStreams get deactivated.
I've done a little bit of field research, and analysing the behaviour of say, Google Meet, this does not happen. When I revoke the permissions, the video stream or audio stream remain untouched.
Right now, what I'm doing is: if the permission is revoked, relaunch the getUserMedia function with only video or audio allowed. I want to understand why this happens, and if maybe the getUserMedia function uses some context that sets this behaviour.
I have read the Media Capture and Streams W3C Draft, and the WebRTC Overview, but I seem unable to find an answer.

So you mean you go to chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=[YOUR_SITE] and toggle only one of either "Camera" or "Microphone" and all the streams are blocked? Sounds like it's a browser thing where they block all gUM related streams until you reload the page. This kinda makes sense because an user that decides to revoke the page access to either could want to revoke it for both, ASAP. Note that testing against Google Meet in Chrome isn't very wise, they (at least used to) have some code that would call an always installed browser extension and thus have higher privileges than you.

I have not thought about the higher privileges, it might be that. Also, no, I'm requesting access for both microphone and camera at the same time, with the same prompt. When the user toggles the permission for the camera or the video, both of the streams get disabled.

Yes, but both permissions are disabled separately, though if you think of it, why would someone suddenly want to disable the permission they gave to a website for accessing whether their mic or cam? Maybe they did accept by accident. In that case it's best to shut down everything as soon as possible and let the user reload the page so that the actual new settings are set. (You should see a dialog asking to reload the page).

This is an interesting enough question to be filed on https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues
It indeed seems that when you have a combined GUM call revoking access to either triggers the ended event even on the single-GUM calls of the type where permission was not revoked.
Might be an implementation bug but folks there will tell you
